# adding a library reference prob

Tags: android

I have just added a library to my project via the Properties - Android - Add Library route.  Before adding everything was fine but after adding my project has not generated a R.java file and so I have a bunch of R cannot be resolved errors.  Is there some aspect of adding a library that I have missed that would account for the non generation of the resource table?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little fiddly in Eclipse but if you get such errors

1) Refresh the project (click on project and F5) to make sure Eclipse knows about all your files on disk.

2) Clean the project (Click Projects (top menu in Eclipse) --> Clean Projects --> Make sure your project is selected --> Click OK.

Comment: I had cleaned it before and got yhe errors, I tried the F5 and then clean but still errors

Comment: Which version of the Android tools are you using (Library projects have changed significantly in the latest R15 version)

Comment: Also make sure that there are no name conflicts in the R class of the library project and your project

Comment: I seem to have solved it by including an import in the main project files with the package name followed by .R

Comment: Whoops I spoke too soon.   When the library is added then the import line errors with import .... .R cannot be resolved.